# How does iOS notifications handle cases without content-available key

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I'm troubleshooting an existing codebase where notifciations do not appear to be firing or at least are not firing to my understanding.

Things I have found in testing:
Context: The feature is chat

1. Notifications will fire from the server if the chat window is open.
2. If the app is in the background or killed the notifications do not appear (the payload below is a sample payload that is being sent).
3. If I add `content-available` the notifications fire as they should with the app in the background. However, we're not wanting to use that key because we don't want to over extend our notification budget.

```swift
[
        "aps": [
          "alert": [
            "body": "Body Message,
            "title-loc-key": "title key,
          ],
        ],
        "source": "mySource",
        "type": "NewChatMessage",
        "unreadCount": "1",
      ]
```

I'm at a knowledge gap here on how else notifications would be firing without `content-available`.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You say "If the app is in the background or killed the notifications do appear" - this is the expected behaviour. What do think should happen?

Comment: They do not appear when in the background or when killed with the current payload I've provided above.

Comment: So, they, *do not* appear - it is a typo in your question.  Have you asked for and received notification permission from the user?

Comment: Yes overall other notifications work and if I add the key `content-available` the notifications will appear, but if I remove that key notifications do not appear. I guess my big question is adding that key the only way to get background notifications?

As for the typo, are you refertring to `notifications will fire from the server if the chat window is open`? That's the only time notifications appear wirh the current payload.

Comment: I am referring to the sentence in your question "If the app is in the background or killed the notifications do appear" - if they do appear, what is the problem?

Comment: yes, but only if `content-available` is added and we're not wanting to add that for the fear over putting our push notifications over budget by the APNS server.

Comment: Then how are points 2 and 3 in your question different? And you have asked for and received permission for your app to display notifications?

Comment: Ok I was missing the exact spot where the issue lied in my question and I've updated it. Let me know if that clears it up.

Comment: Ok.  So once more - Have you asked for and received notification permission from the user?  Where do you expect the notifications to appear?  If you have notification permission then the notifications will appear on the device Lock Screen and notification history depending on the exact notification settings the user has selected.

Comment: Yes. I don't think we're discussing the same issue. My issue is with #2 and the existing payload as I provided above where `content-available` is not part of the payload.

Comment: I understand that, but what I am trying to understand is what you *expect* to happen.  When your app is in the foreground, incoming notifications are delivered to a delegate function and your app can display a notification in the app.  When your app is in the background, the notification is not delivered to your app.  It is displayed by iOS itself, but for that to happen your app needs to have asked the user for notification permission and received that permission.

Comment: Yes we have permissions. Please assume going forward that has been done because other notifications work just fine. It's in this case where the chat notifications do not appear on the lock screen.